# how to replace ampersand to backslash and id to name rewrite url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working with eCommerce website .where i have product detail page .In PHP , anchor Tag look like

```
  <a href="Product-Detail.php?<?php echo $rowProductsFirstWithThreeLimit['MainCategoryName'] ;?>&<?php echo $rowProductsFirstWithThreeLimit['SubCategoryName'] ;?>&ProductId=<?php echo $rowProductsFirstWithThreeLimit['Id'];?>" title="<?php echo $rowProductsFirstWithThreeLimit['MainCategoryName'] ;?>">Product name</a>
```

in address bar i want to Convert Following URL `Product-Detail.php?Kurtis&Cotton&ProductId=47` To  `Product-Detail.php/Kurtis/Cotton/Title` Please Tell Me how can i Rewrite Url in Following Style Thanks In Advance .

Comment: can you please share the output url

Comment: There are about 53566830 examples for exactly this alone here on SO. None of those examples helped you with your specific issue? _Why not?_ And why should the 53566831st example make a difference then?

Comment: Output of URL Product-Detail.php?Kurtis&Cotton&ProductId=47 kalai M